# A question about the "state-transition-matrix" of a physical system,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations, control-theory

Here's a simple but potential research problem that I am learning about.

Let's say I am studying a physical system that is governed by N objects.  At each time, each object is either "active" and given the number "1" or inactive and given the number "0".

So, the system has $2^N$ possible states.

Now, if I am able to compute and find the state-transition-matrix of this system, it should be a $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix.

(Computability of the matrix is a different question.)

But what I am confused about is this:  if I am understanding this problem correctly, the state-transition-matrix is a generalization of the transition matrix of, say, an Ergodic Markov Chain - a matrix that most students learn from basic probability theory (the entries are nonnegative and represent probabilities).  Applying the transition matrix to a probability vector "updates" the probability vector that describes the Markov Chain.

But, is the same thing true of the more general state-transition-matrix of the physical system -- a system that is not necessarily a Markov Chain?

I.e., if I can compute this state-transition-matrix, would applying this matrix to some vector then "update" the vector that describes the current state of the system?

If the answer to the above is "yes", then I see one technical issue:

the matrix multiplication wouldn't make sense, as I would be applying a $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix to an **N-tuple vector**, with each component taking on the values 1 or 0.  The vector wouldn't be of length $2^N$.

Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If each of the $2^N$ states corresponds to a single row/column of the transition matrix, then the same must be true of the state vector.

Comment: ...a $2^N$-tuple state vector seems strange, though @amd.  Wouldn't it be an N-tuple, with each component taking the value of either 1 or 0, to describe the governing objects as being "active" or "inactive"?  Thanks,

Comment: ...so that there are $2^N$ possible N-tuples that describe the system @amd.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: ah, ok I got it now @amd.  Can I please ask you a few follow-up questions?  Are the entries...probabilities or not necessarily?  And does applying the matrix to the state vector "update" the state vector, just like in the case of transition matrices (of Markov chains) that update the probability vector?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 are you working on Markov Jump Linear Systems?

Comment: Hi @WG, I am actually not sure whether my system is Markov - I have to ask my professor soon - but my main priority was to first understand state-transition-matrices.  After a short meeting today with another prof, I don't think that the matrix I am working with is a *probability* transition matrix.

Comment: So, what do the elements of this matrix represent? That should tell you what the vectors that it’s meant to be used with mean.

Comment: @User001, do you have multiple state matrices $A_i$ of $\dot{x} = A_ix + B_iu$? And do you have a transition state $P$ with the probabilities to which your state $i$ you jump? That is to say. a hybrid system but the state jump is goverend by a Markov System? If so, then you have a Markov Jump Linear System ;-). Check also http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM08/pdf/ncs-markjls_22Jan10.pdf. Furthermore, it would be much better for us to help you if you simply state your whole problem including the matrices et cetera.